# Regex to find 2 or more multi-word strings in entire document (either string first)

Tags: regex

I need some help with how to make a regex that matches only if 2 or more multi-word strings exist anywhere in the entire document, and any of the strings could appear first or last or in any order in the document.

I have found tons of examples that work for 2 stings, but they all have the requirement that the strings appear in order.

Due to the limitations of where this is being evaluated, it also has to be a single line/single evaluation. It isn't in something like bash where I can pipe output of 1 regex into another regex.

(?s).*?\bFoo\b.+?\bBar\b.*

Is a great example that I found on stack overflow. But it only works in order and doesn't work with multi-word strings, only single word.

So for this string for example:

> In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum (derived from Latin dolorem ipsum, translated as "pain itself") is a filler text commonly used to demonstrate the graphic elements of a document or visual presentation. Replacing meaningful content with placeholder text allows viewers to focus on graphic aspects such as font, typography, and page layout without being distracted by the content. It also reduces the need for the designer to come up with meaningful text, as they can instead use quickly-generated lorem ipsum.

I would need to be able to match "graphic design" and "filler text", but I would need it to match if either one of those comes first.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `.*?\b(graphic design)\b.*?\b(filler text)\b|.*?\b(filler text)\b.*?\b(graphic design)\b` https://regex101.com/r/4unuvi/1

Comment: I'll do some testing with that to see if it works for this. You kind of went down the road that I was hoping I wouldn't have to, where you are basically writing the regex once for each ORDER that they would appear in. So if testing for 3 strings, the regex would basically have to include string orders 1-2-3, 1-3-2, 2-1-3, 2-3-1, 3-1-2, and 3-2-1 variants? This will get unruly very fast if there isn't a way to test for all orders in once pass and I can't rule out the need in the future for 4 or 5 stings.

Comment: Do you mean like this with lookaheads? `^(?=.*?\bgraphic design\b).*?\bfiller text.*` https://regex101.com/r/3SNXzw/1

Answer (score 0):

Use a look ahead for each phrase:

```
^(?=.*\bgraphic design\b)(?=.*\bfiller text\b).*
```

Word boundaries have been added to not match "infographic designation" for example.

---

To check for more phrases, use another lookahead for each phrase. For example, to also require `aaa bbb ccc` and `xxx yyy zzz`:

```
^(?i)(?=.*\bgraphic design\b)(?=.*\bfiller text\b)(?=.*\baaa bbb ccc\b)(?=.*\bxxx yyy zzz\b).*
```

Adding `(?i)` makes it case insensitive.

Comment: Both examples seem to work but I am unable to get a 3rd or 4th string added. I also figured out how to make the entire thing case insensitive with this example. (?i)^(?=.*?\bgraphic design\b).*?\bfiller text.*